# How can I run PyQt5 in sublime text

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt5, sublimetext3

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
import sys

def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setGeometry(200, 200, 300, 300)
    win.setWindowTitle("Tech wit me")
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
window()
```

i wrote this piece of code and just got black screen. It works on spyder but ST makes issue. Can you help me about that?

Comment: Define "makes issue"; what kind of issue? Sublime only tells an external Python interpreter that you've installed and configured to run the file as you asked. Are you seeing some sort of error message?

Comment: Sorry i'm bad at english. I mean when i run this code on Sublime text, it just giving me black screen, there isn't any error message or something.

Comment: @ibrahim How do you run your script? Do you press Ctrl + B?

Comment: @eyllanesc yes. I'm using that shortcut

Comment: try: 1. "Tools" menu -> "Build System -> select "Python". 2. "Tools" menu -> "Build". 3. "Tools" menu -> "Build Results" -> "Show Build Results" to see what the problem is.

Comment: @ToSimplicity I did this and still get any error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a small change to your Sublime Text configuration, so that the problem may fix.

Just follow this:

`Tools > Build System > New Build system`

and Copy this and paste it

```
{ 
 "cmd":["C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python38-32/python.exe", "-u", "$file"], 
 "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)", 
 "selector": "source.python",
 "shell": "true",
}
```

instead of `<username>`, use your username. Instead of `Python38-32`, use your Python version. `38` denotes the Python version 3.8 and `32` denotes the 32 bit architecture.

The line `'shell": "True",` is added.

Hope this works.